# Does 悍ましい derive from a verb?

Tags: verbs, conjugations, adjectives, i-adjectives, okurigana

So I'm confused about おぞましい, because in 悍ましい, there's おくりがな. Atleast I'm sure of it, and as far as I know, おくりがな is added to a verb. So, I'd think that the ま in 悍ましい、is from the irrealis form of a verb, and verbs that end in む irrealis form usually end with ま、like 望ま、楽しま、悲しま,苦しま etc.
So with that, I'd think that おぞましい's origin would be a verb named おぞむ, and, for example, like あえて, I can't even find a verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a separate post back in December 2020 about the derivation of *-ashii* adjectives:

- [む verbs and corresponding ましい adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/82922/%e3%82%80-verbs-and-corresponding-%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%84-adjectives/82923#82923)

In short, it appears that most *-ashii* adjectives derive from verbs.  Note too that *-oshii* appears as a variant form, sometimes alongside *-ashii* (as in 好【この】ましい and 好【この】もしい), and sometimes as the only extant form (as in よろしい).

So if you see an adjective ending in *-ashii* or *-oshii*, chances are high that this is derived from a verb.

Answer (score 1):

Okurigana is used in i-adjectives as well, look for example at 新しい (new). So, okurigana doesn't necessary mean that the word is a verb/derived from a verb.

<strike>Besides, it seems that 悍 doesn't appear within any verb</strike>
See @jogloran's link in comments for the potential source verb.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this to me.

Comment: I think this answer may be wrong — see https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10142250095

Comment: @jogloran in what regard? That not only verbs have okurigana? Unless you consider all adjectives verbs, I think you can't argue with that. Or that 悍 does not appear within any verb? Of that I am not sure, that's why I wrote "it seems"

Comment: No, the part I fear is incorrect is your claim that the adjective doesn't derive from a verb. The answer I linked suggests that a verb おぞむ existed in the past.

Comment: Tbh, I think I misjudged the question and was too eager to answer.

Comment: @jogloran perhaps it would be better to move your link from comments to a separate answer lest it gets lost in all the replies.